# Sharing multiple photos on Instagram

Tags: ios, instagram

Now that Instagram supports [multiple photos per post](http://blog.instagram.com/post/157572774352/170222-multiple), I'd like to take advantage of this feature in my app.

Instagram document how to share a single photo in their [developer documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/), but neither of their solutions work for more than one photo (`UIDocumentInteractionController` doesn't support more than one file).

I've also tried using a UIActivityController and including either the UIImage instances or NSURL file references, but this also just shares the first image with Instagram.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Currently it seems the answer is no. The API also currently doesn't support retrieving more than the first photo in a multi-photo post.

Comment: How do apps like Swipeable do it then? https://9to5mac.com/2017/03/22/instagram-pano-360-photos/

Comment: Swipeable (while a really cool app) isn't actually loading in multiple photos to Instagram. They are loading just one (the one with the instructions on it). Then you're required to tap the "multiple photos icon" and select the two or more from your panorama. Swipeable creates these squares from your panorama as well as the instruction bookend photos and adds them to your camera roll so when you open Instagram they are right there, ready to be posted.

Comment: Of course - you're correct. Thanks!

Comment: @simonmaddox Hi I want to share multiple photos on instagram as single post.
Can you please help me to achieve this. Did you get anything for multiple sharing ?

Comment: No, read the comment by @iamwonder above. It's not currently possible with the Instagram API or app. They do explain how it's possible to load multiple photos into Instagram, but it's very much a manual process.

Comment: Although the documentation is still the same. Does anyone know if anything has changed about this?